# Android Printing Plain Text and Possibly PDF

Tags: android, pdf, printing

So I have sort of an odd requirement in an Android app I'm writing. Here's a quick summary.

There is a product detail page in the app. From that page the user should be able to print the details for that product. This, in itself, would be pretty easy by creating a print adapter or print from a webview.

But the secondary part of the requirement is to include a PDF document in the printing *if* the product has one. <-- That's the part that is tripping me up.

I can print a PDF by itself. I can print plain text by itself.

**But how do I print plain text and a PDF together in one print job?**

This is the first app I've built that is using printing, so I'm not super clear on all the ins and outs. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**

Based off the suggestion by @TimBiegeleisen, I looked in [PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) and it worked great for merging. It was a bit sluggish when creating a simple PDF so I used Android's [`PdfDocument`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.html) to create a PDF then used PDFBox to merge it with the other PDF. The following is an example of what eventually worked:

```
View rootView = getLayoutInflater()
    .inflate(R.layout.pdf_layout_sample, null, false)
    .findViewById(R.id.print_kit_detail);

((TextView) rootView
    .findViewById(R.id.dynamic_text))
    .setText(R.string.some_text);

PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();

// this creates an 8.5" x 11" PDF with .5" margins
PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(612, 792, 1)
    .setContentRect(new Rect(36, 36, 576, 756))
    .create();
PdfDocument.Page page = document.startPage(pageInfo);

Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
int pageWidth = canvas.getWidth();
int pageHeight = canvas.getHeight();
int measureWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(pageWidth, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
int measuredHeight = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(pageHeight, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

rootView.measure(measureWidth, measuredHeight);
rootView.layout(0, 0, pageWidth, pageHeight);
rootView.draw(canvas);

document.finishPage(page);

try {
    File file = File.createTempFile("temp_file", ".pdf");
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
    document.writeTo(os);
    document.close();
    os.close();

    // PDFBox usage starts here
    PDFMergerUtility merger = new PDFMergerUtility();
    merger.setDestinationFileName(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/created-filename.pdf");
    merger.addSource(file.getAbsolutePath());
    merger.addSource(new File("path-to-product.pdf"));
    merger.mergeDocuments();

    // The code to print...
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into something like iText for Android?  You can write your own text content to a PDF template.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I hadn't until you just mentioned it. But looking at the license, it won't work for me unfortunately. But it looks like it'd be perfect. I'm working on the project on a volunteer basis, so I can't pay for it. And the project is closed-source, so I can't use it unless I pay for it.

Comment: Check PDFBox, the other major Java PDF library.  Perhaps the licensing terms are better.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen PDFBox seems to work great. It's a bit slow, but it is doing what I need it to. Thanks! If you post this as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: I can't post an answer because neither of us posted any code.